# Get projected coordinates from geometric coordinates

Tags: matplotlib, cartopy

I have a map figure rendered with Cartopy and Matplotlib. I have a specific geometric coordinate (in lat/lon) and I would like to know the pixel coordinate closest to this geometric coordinate's projection (if it is visible), for instance to draw a graphic over the coordinate on the map.

(Note I don't want to draw *with* Matplotlib; I'm exporting the figure as a bitmap image and drawing in a different part of the pipeline.)

[This documentation](https://matplotlib.org/users/transforms_tutorial.html) suggests it might be something like this:

```py
import cartopy, matplotlib.pyplot

fig = matplotlib.pyplot.figure()
ax = fig.add_axes([0, 0, 1, 1], projection=cartopy.crs.Orthographic())
ax.add_feature(cartopy.feature.LAND, facecolor='black')

# Print the location of New York City in display coordinates
lon, lat = -74.0060, 40.7128
trans = cartopy.crs.Geodetic()._as_mpl_transform(ax)
x, y = trans.transform((lon, lat))
print(x, y)

# Or this way
projx, projy = ax.projection.transform_point(lon, lat, cartopy.crs.Geodetic())
x, y = ax.transData.transform((projx, projy))
print(x, y)
```

Though interestingly, if I plot this point, the figure centers on and zooms into Manhattan, and then the output display coordinates are indeed in the center of the figure at (640, 480).

```
matplotlib.pyplot.plot(lon, lat, marker='o', color='red', markersize=12,
    alpha=0.7, transform=cartopy.crs.Geodetic())
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just found that the transforms are not properly set until the figure is in its final state. So the key is to first draw the figure,

```
fig.canvas.draw()
```

or at least apply the aspect properly.

```
ax.apply_aspect()
```

Then you will get the correct pixel coordinates out,

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cartopy
import cartopy.crs as ccrs

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_axes([0, 0, 1, 1], projection=ccrs.PlateCarree())
ax.add_feature(cartopy.feature.LAND, facecolor='black')
ax.set_global()

# before being able to call any of the transforms, the figure needs to be drawn
fig.canvas.draw()
# or
# ax.apply_aspect()

# Print the location of New York City in display coordinates
lon, lat = -74.0060, 40.7128
trans = ccrs.PlateCarree()._as_mpl_transform(ax)
x, y = trans.transform_point((lon, lat))
print(x,y)

plt.show()
```

This prints:

```
188.43377777777778 312.3783111111111
```

Note that those coordinates refer to the pixels from the lower left corner.

Comment: It doesn't seem that you can add Cartopy projections and Matplotlib Transform objects, though looking at [this example](https://scitools.org.uk/cartopy/docs/v0.15/examples/eyja_volcano.html) it might be something like `trans = cartopy.crs.Geodetic()._as_mpl_transform(ax) + ax.transData`, but the values are still wrong.

I'll add an example to the question.

Comment: Yep, `_as_mpl_transform` would be needed. I updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

In my sample code I failed to specify the extent of the map. If I add

```py
ax.set_global()
```

then the transformed coordinates are sensible.

I presented two ways to compute the transformed coordinates, but the way with `_as_mpl_transform()` seems to return the center point when New York City is not visible. The way with `ax.projection.transform_point()` returns NaN when off-screen.