# Getting display coordinated from cartopy generated image plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, cartopy

I have need to plot point on the map, produce PNG image on that map and, output display coordinated of the plotted point.

Using cartopy I could get the map I wanted and plot a point in given lon/lat coordinates.

I cannot figure out how to get the pixel coordinates out. I tried to follow simple matplotlib tutorial https://matplotlib.org/users/transforms_tutorial.html  But it does not work as expected in this situation

```py
import cartopy.crs as ccrs
import cartopy.feature as cfeature
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Create Mercator projection with dateline in the middle:
from matplotlib import lines

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10, 10))
ax = plt.axes(projection=ccrs.Mercator(central_longitude=26,))
ax.set_extent([19, 33, 59.5, 70.5], crs=ccrs.PlateCarree())


LAND = cfeature.NaturalEarthFeature('physical', 'land', '50m',
                                    edgecolor='face',
                                    facecolor=cfeature.COLORS['land'], zorder=-1)

ax.add_feature(LAND)
ax.coastlines(resolution='50m')

ax.add_feature(cfeature.NaturalEarthFeature('cultural', 'admin_0_boundary_lines_land',
                              '50m', edgecolor='black', facecolor='none'))


plt.plot([26.7042], [60.8679],  color='blue', linewidth=2, marker='o',
         transform=ccrs.PlateCarree(),
         )

fig.canvas.draw()
# print image x y coordinates of point 60.8679° N, 26.7042° E here

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Maybe you want to show what you have tried? Also did you search for similar problems? I have a vague memory seeing a similar question already (or even having answered it myself).

Comment: Please check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55998371/get-projected-coordinates-from-geometric-coordinates

Comment: All of my trials were so off so I decided to erase them from the example code.